# Uploading 1000s of files to AWS Notebook Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

When I open AWS Notebook Instance-> Jupyter Notebook. It gives me a storage (probably called an S3 bucket). I created a folder there and tried to upload 1000s of data. However, it asks me to manually click on the upload button next to every single file. Is it possible to upload that data much easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [AWS-CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-move) or the [AWS-S3 SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) (JS in this example).